# JavaScript (ES6) and fetch(): How can I throw an error so that catch triggers? (Testing it with Jest)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, jestjs, es6-promise

I thought I was decent at JavaScript until now. I want to write a helper function for my HTTP requests. I tested it with Jest. The problem is that the `catch()` part does not get triggered. Let me give you the test first:

```
it("recognizes when a response's status is not okay", () => {
  fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ ok: false }));

  expect.assertions(1);

  return getRequestWithoutHeader(fullTestUrl).catch(err => {
    expect(err.ok).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Maybe the test is written wrongly which fails. Anyways here is the helper function that I did write. I tried out different implementations and they all fail the test:

```
// Implementation one: with throw
export const getRequestWithoutHeader = fullUrlRoute =>
  fetch(fullUrlRoute).then(response =>
    response.json().then(json => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(json);
      }
      return json;
    }, error => error)
  );

// Implementation two: with throw new
export const getRequestWithoutHeader = fullUrlRoute =>
  fetch(fullUrlRoute).then(response =>
    response.json().then(json => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(json);
      }
      return json;
    }, error => error)
  );

// Implementation three: With Promise.reject
export const getRequestWithoutHeader = fullUrlRoute =>
  fetch(fullUrlRoute).then(response =>
    response.json().then(json => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(json);
      }
      return json;
    }, error => error)
  );

// Implementation four: with new Promise
export const getRequestWithoutHeader = fullUrlRoute =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(fullUrlRoute).then(response =>
      response.json().then(
        json => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            reject(json);
          }
          resolve(json);
        },
        error => reject(error)
      )
    );
  });
```

None of these work. Some of these would return using a `then` in the test, but I want the promise to be thrown. I want to trigger a catch.

How do I have to write this helper function?

Comment: You should check for `ok` *before* calling `.json()` on the `response`. (also, better not to nest Promises like that - that's the promise-as-callback anti-pattern)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Could you please give a code example? I tried to do it like this now: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zjbbpb And it still fails.

Comment: You don't want the nested `.then(json => json);` (if you want to do something with it, put it in an outer `.then` instead). You also don't want to `catch` the error inside `getRequestWithoutHeader`, else it'll return a *resolved* `Promise` (won't be caught by your test)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hmm I still can't get it to work. I now implemented it like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zjbbpb Sorry for being such a hard learner. And thank you very much for your patience and your help!

Comment: Yep, that looks good now! Unfortunately, I don't have experience with Jest, so if that code doesn't work, I don't know what the next step to fix it would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up having to do:

I used [jest-fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) for mocking the requests.

In order for the promise to be correctly rejected, I had to overrite the `init` argument of the `mockResponseOnce` function.

Here is how the test ended up looking:

```
  it("recognizes when a response's status is not okay", () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ someResponse: "someResponse" }), { status: 403 });
    expect.assertions(1);

    return getRequestWithHeader(fullTestUrl, article).catch(err => {
      expect(err.someResponse).toEqual("someResponse");
    });
  });
```

By setting the status explicitly, it automatically sets `ok: false` in the response, triggering the function.

I also applied [CertainPerfomance's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) tips and refactored the function like this:

```
export const getRequestWithoutHeader = fullUrlRoute =>
  fetch(fullUrlRoute)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(response);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
  fetch(fullUrlRoute)
  .then(response =>{
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      else throw response
  })
  .then(json=> {
      console.log(json);
    })
  .catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)
   });
```

Hope this help you

Comment: This is basically my implementation two, just that it does not work, because with your way of nesting it, `response` is undefined when checkin `!response.ok`.

Comment: try to print console.log(response) just after fetch like .then(response =>{console.log(response)})

Comment: It you don't get any response, then you are doing it in wrong way. Visiit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch